# How can you define your own pseudo element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to define my own pseudo element in JavaScript, without using any attributes, or css 'hacks' and compromises. The pseudo element must be more like the `::first-child` that is static, not `:hover`, which is only applied when the mouse is hovering, or doing something. 
The closest I could come to that was:

**html:**

```
<red ::second-child>ygu</red>
```

**CSS:**

```
[\:\:second\-child] {
    color: red;
}
```

But, that is obviously only an attribute, and I would like it to be done in JavaScript without needing to apply the `::second-child` as an attribute, and as a proper pseudo class in css. For example: `red::second-child {}`

My aim is to apply css with `::second-child`, but I would like the JavaScript to be able to be applied in the same way to make other pseudo classes like `::third-child` as well.

Comment: Look at the [Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle) code base, they have pseudo classes in there.

Comment: I would prefer not to use a plugin

Comment: @ScriptKitty: I think the suggestion was that what you're trying to do is similar, and so the code there may be useful as a reference. I'm not sure what you're trying to do *is* similar, but if it is, it's a good suggestion.

Comment: This is not a pseudo-class, it's a pseudo-**element**, and it's definitely not an "event".

Comment: Oops!, it should be more accurate now.

Comment: ...why? `:nth-child(2)` and `:nth-child(3)` are already selectors.

Comment: It's not for utility... I would just like to know if you can do it, or the closest you can get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: You can't, if you want the browser to do the work when applying the styling.

If you're applying this stuff with JavaScript anyway, you're best off using classes, to get the advantage of the optimization browsers apply.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I cannot do this after scouring the web. This will have to be the answer.